# Are there verbs that are always reflexive besides "perjure"?

Tags: verbs, reflexives

On a recent newscast on CNN, an analyst said,

> Trump's lawyers want to avoid questions that might challenge his recollection and lead him to **perjure himself**.

Hearing this got me to thinking about the nature of the word **perjure** in that it can only be applied to oneself.  Someone else can't perjure you, you can only perjure yourself.

I wondered if there was a term for this, and in searching on Google I found this Wikipedia page on ["reflexive verbs"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflexive_verb), and it actually uses "perjure" as an example.  But the wording is a little confusing and implies that many verbs can *function* as reflexive verbs but they are not *always* used this way.  On the other hand, "perjure" as used in the Wikipedia example seems to be a case where it is always reflexive.

> In grammar, a **reflexive verb** is, loosely, a verb whose direct object is the same as its subject, for example, "I wash myself". More generally, a reflexive verb has the same semantic agent and patient (typically represented syntactically by the subject and the direct object). For example, the English verb *to perjure* is reflexive since one can only *perjure* oneself.

Is there a term for verbs that are limited or mostly limited to reflexive use, such as *perjure*?  Are there other words, or a whole category of words, that can only be used this way?

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/137285/reflexive-only-verbs